# How to get eclipse to use jars installed on application server

Tags: eclipse, jar, buildpath, geronimo

Hi I use eclipse and geronimo application server 2.1

I have installed some Jars that were held in the lib folder of the EAR to the server and deleted them from the EAR. But eclipse will not recognise that they exist. I have added the dependancies as described here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/GMOxDOC22/adding-jars-to-the-geronimo-repository.html

I think its may have something to do with the jars not appearing under the server runtime environment in the java build path.

Could anyone please help me get eclipse to recognise those jars on the server?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate what you want? What does "installed some Jars" means? Installation on geronimo as part of your WAR file? Or installation in some directory? Perhaps it would help to see the directory tree of Geronimo, and your local tree, and to see which jars you want to use where.

Comment: My application requires the use of a number of jar files. I wish to include these on the server rather than in the lib folder of the app. So I went to geronimo's console and 'installed' the jars. (geronimo provides an interface for uploading the jars to the server. Thats all fine. My application would likely work once installed. The problem now is eclipse doesnt recognise those jars as being on the classpath. How can I add them to the classpath by linking to those on the app server?

Comment: Go to Project - Java - Build Path, and add the jars to the build path.

Comment: but then those jars get included in the ear. A way to refrence those on the server should surely be the way?

Comment: I've not created an EAR with Eclipse for a long time, but I think you just need to uncheck it in the *Order and Export* tab of the build path dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back at this question with more knowledge, I would add these manually to the build path in eclipse.